# How to call a function in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, function

Im fairly new at visual basic and im having trouble using function. ive tried many ways but failed, so ive deleted the funtion to start again. i want this function to run once someone has clicked a button, however the button is on a different form.

When button(btnAdd) is clicked on form 2 i want this to run on form one...

```
    Using writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath", True)
        Dim recipient As String = tbRecipient.Text
        If (tbRecipient.Lines.Count > 1) Then
            recipient = ""
            For Each line As String In tbRecipient.Lines
                recipient = recipient & " " & line
            Next
            recipient = recipient.Trim()
        End If
        writer.WriteLine(recipient)
    End Using
```

Im not sure if this is the right code to achieve what i want it to do. What the code should do is when the user clicks the button add, it reads the checked options in a checklistbox and adds them to a file. that file is the outputted to a different textbox, which is on a different form. I have the funtion working correctly for the adding of the checkboxlist but need to then display it in a text box on another form. if anyone can help or point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click on the button(btnAdd) in design window then write:

myFunction()

then in the second form code window:

public function myFunction()

'your code

end function

Answer (score 0):

just call the function name where you want to execute it, or using the reserved keyword Call as Below:

First Way:

```
'Call by taping the function name
myFunctionName(Argumets)
```

Second Way:

```
'Use the Call Keyword:
Call myFunctionName(Argumets)
```